# Naming Multiple Android Components

Tags: android, user-interface, naming

I am working on an Android app but I am a little bit confused on naming multiple instances of **TextView** / **Switch** pairs.

My manifest file for those items is like:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question1"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#212121"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:textColor="#616161"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
```

The thing is I will have more than 20 pairs like this and is there any convention to name multiple instances of UI components? Considering the layout and the order of these item pairs are subject to change, I don't want to name those components as **question1** or **switch1**. I also don't want to give them very specific and long names because it would be harder to maintain at the backend, so I am looking for a general way should there be any.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to access the components from the code and looking for a simple way, right?

Comment: why don't you use `ListView` then ?

Comment: I am not populating the question switch pairs from somewhere, can I add texview and switch and access them easily. Because they will have different logic once switch status changes. @semihyagcioglu yes, if there is a simple and better way I will move to that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using something in between. I guess there is not a silver bullet for your problem not that I know of any. But you can probably start giving better names in a **more general fashion** such as follows.

```
question_label_your_age
switch_your_age
```

I guess this way you can access them easier with your ide, and they would be more informative.

Comment: Well my question texts might be far longer than those but this would be a lot better. Thanks!